# Scriptmanger.registerclientscript not working while downloading file c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I am trying to call a javascript function through `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

Here is my code:

```
   renderedBytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
   Response.Clear();
   Response.ClearContent();
   Response.ClearHeaders();
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=AttendanceReport-" + txtStartDate.Text + "_" + txtEndDate.Text + "." + fileNameExtension);
   Response.ContentType = mimeType;
   Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);                    
   HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script1", "$(document).ready(function () { StopLoader(); });", true);
   Response.Flush();
```

I am trying to call the function **StopLoader()** once the download has been done. I have tried using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` but the same thing is happening with both these.

I have also called the javascript function **StopLoader()** in `document.ready()` also but since the page is not reloading, the function is not called.

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Comment: you are delivering a file to the browser. the browser will initiate the download "workflow", that is ask the user whether to open, save, save as, ...
there is just no clean way to inject that client script back into your originating page header (maybe window.opener would work here?). what do you want to achieve? a "downloading" animation is provided by browsers' UI anyway.

Comment: @dlatikay the thing is that i want to show a 'UI blocker or loader symbol' once we click on the download button. I am able to block the UI on the click of download but not able to remove that......